# How to solve this 3rd degree polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I looked up the [factoring method](http://www.wikihow.com/Factor-a-Cubic-Polynomial), but I think this one is calculated using a calculator. With a basic calculator, how do I set this up?

$16x^3 - 18x^2 - 2x  - 1 = 0$

I factored it to become...  $2x(8x^2-9x-2)=1$

In my note book I had it as $x = 1.06272$. I would like to learn how I can set it up for the basic (non-graphing) calculator.

Comment: What is the expected amount of time for this problem?

Comment: In general it's much harder(time consuming) to solve qubic polynomials, you can use the qubic formula described here: http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/courses/cubic/

Comment: You're probably required to use the Newton-Rapshon method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: It looks quite complicated, let me try to look into the links...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Newton-Rapshon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

1. Calculate the derivative $f'(x)=48x^2-36x-2$.
2. Choose an arbitrary point where to start the iteration (usually one you think is close to a root). I'll choose $x_0=1$.
3. Calculate the next point of the iteration as $$ x_1=x_0-\frac{f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)},$$ which in this case is $x_1=1-\frac{-5}{10}=1.5$
4. Repeat the process by defining $$x_{n+1} = x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}.$$ In this case, the next term is $$x_2=1.5-\frac{f(1.5)}{f'(1.5)}=1.5-\frac{9.5}{52}=1.317307692.$$

And I'll do it a couple more times because the convergence is pretty cool. You can verify that:

$$x_3 = 1.266976947\text{ and } x_4=1.263154315.$$

Which are actually quite close to the [root](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16x%5E3-18x%5E2-2x-1%3D0), which is approximately $x=1.26313285$.

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16x%5E3-18x%5E2-2x-1%3D0) finds the real root to be about $1.2631$, far from your notebook.  You can see that the root is between $1$ and $2$ by checking the signs (which you should have done as part of the rational root test).  If I had a non-programmable calculator, I would use bisection, testing $1.5, 1.25, 1.375$, etc.